# Cannot install Node Inspector

Tags: node.js, debugging

I tried the installation on two different Windows 10 machines, both with admin privileges and node v8.6.0. + python 3.6.3 amd64. Both failed with the same errors:

```
C:\Users\kians>npm install -g node-inspector

> v8-profiler@5.7.0 preinstall C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-profiler
> node -e 'process.exit(0)'


> v8-debug@1.0.1 preinstall C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug
> node -e 'process.exit(0)'

C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-inspector -> C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\bin\inspector.js                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-debug -> C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\bin\node-debug.js

> v8-debug@1.0.1 install C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/debug/v1.0.1/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for v8-debug@1.0.1 and node@8.6.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 

C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node "" clean ) 

C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-w
in32-x64\debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64 )  else (node "" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64\debug.node --module_name=deb
ug --module_path=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64 ) 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\kians\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\kians\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-inspector\\node_modules\\v8-debug\\build\\debug\\v1.0.1\\node-v57-win32-x64\\debug.node" "--module_name=debug" "--module_path=C:\\Users\
\kians\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-inspector\\node_modules\\v8-debug\\build\\debug\\v1.0.1\\node-v57-win32-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug
gyp ERR! node -v v8.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64\debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-w
in32-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kians\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-inspector\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.38
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64\debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! v8-debug@1.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-11T17_39_49_176Z-debug.log
```

First I thought files from aws are not available but at the first step a lot of files are being extracted, so I don't think a failed download is the problem.

I was also able to open: C:\Users\kians\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.EXE

EDIT: I run the following command:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Now the error is different:

```
C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program File
s\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node "" clean ) 

C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program File
s\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\kians
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64\debug.node --module_name=debug --
module_path=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64 --pytho
n=C:\Users\kians\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015 )  else (node "" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users
\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64\debug.node --module_name=de
bug --module_path=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64 -
-python=C:\Users\kians\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015 ) 

C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program File
s\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\kians\App
Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64\debug.node --module_name=debug --modu
le_path=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64 )  else (no
de "" build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0
.1\node-v57-win32-x64\debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules
\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64 ) 
Die Projekte in dieser Projektmappe werden nacheinander erstellt. Um eine parallele Erstellung zu ermöglichen, müssen Sie den Schalter "/m" hi
nzufügen.
  debug.cc
  InjectedScriptHost.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
..\src\debug.cc(41): warning C4996: 'v8::Debug::Call': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspecto
r\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\kians\.node-gyp\8.6.0\include\node\v8-debug.h(195): note: see declaration of 'v8::Debug::Call'
..\src\debug.cc(52): warning C4996: 'v8::Debug::GetDebugContext': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\no
de-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\kians\.node-gyp\8.6.0\include\node\v8-debug.h(209): note: see declaration of 'v8::Debug::GetDebugContext'
..\src\debug.cc(57): warning C4996: 'v8::Debug::SendCommand': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-i
nspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\kians\.node-gyp\8.6.0\include\node\v8-debug.h(172): note: see declaration of 'v8::Debug::SendCommand'
..\src\debug.cc(78): error C2039: 'GetMirror': is not a member of 'v8::Debug' [C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector
\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\kians\.node-gyp\8.6.0\include\node\v8-debug.h(26): note: see declaration of 'v8::Debug'
..\src\debug.cc(78): error C3861: 'GetMirror': identifier not found [C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modu
les\v8-debug\build\debug.vcxproj]
..\src\debug.cc(71): warning C4996: 'v8::Debug::GetDebugContext': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\no
de-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\kians\.node-gyp\8.6.0\include\node\v8-debug.h(209): note: see declaration of 'v8::Debug::GetDebugContext'
..\src\debug.cc(80): warning C4996: 'v8::Debug::GetDebugContext': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\no
de-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\kians\.node-gyp\8.6.0\include\node\v8-debug.h(209): note: see declaration of 'v8::Debug::GetDebugContext'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js
" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\kians\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-inspector\\node_modules\\v8-debug\\build
\\debug\\v1.0.1\\node-v57-win32-x64\\debug.node" "--module_name=debug" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\kians\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\n
ode-inspector\\node_modules\\v8-debug\\build\\debug\\v1.0.1\\node-v57-win32-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug
gyp ERR! node -v v8.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64\debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=C:\Users\kians\App
Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\node-pre-
gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kians\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-inspector\\node_m
odules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.38
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules
\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64\debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\n
ode-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v1.0.1\node-v57-win32-x64' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                      
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! v8-debug@1.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kians\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-11T18_45_47_242Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does is still make sense to use `node-inspector` for Node.js 8? Read this: https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I did not knew this one and will use it now. Would you like to post this as an answer, so I can marked it solve and you will be rewarded with points?

Answer (score 2):

According to thread https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/1010#issuecomment-306972510, node inspector is not working with node 8.X.

you can use the built-in debugger tools. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/

Answer (score 1):

To begin with this error seems to be related with the `node-gyp` package. According to their documentation [page](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) in github there are 2 setup options for Windows.

Option 1 is to run:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tool
```

Which you have already done, but in my experience did not work for me as well.

Try option 2 as well:

1. Install Visual C++ Build Tools using the Default Install option.
2. Install Visual Studio 2015 (or modify an existing installation) and select Common Tools for Visual C++ during setup. This also works with the free Community and Express for Desktop editions.
3. Install Python 2.7 (v3.x.x is not supported), and run npm config set python python2.7 (or see below for further instructions on specifying the proper Python version and path.)
4. Launch cmd, npm config set msvs_version 2015

Comment: Thank you. I ran npm install --global --production windows-build-tool already. Please see the middle of my post. The first error disappeared but then I have new errors.

Comment: @Binary Yes, I noticed - that's why I said "which you have already done". But give the 2nd option a try as well since the 1st option did not work for me as well while the 2nd did.